# For loop for checking the 'state' of certain windows' services

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

#### `services.txt` contains:-

Plugplay
spooler
dhcp

---

I want to check the status of some services that are specified in file `services.txt`. I am using for loop for this.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a IN ('type services.txt') do call :chkservice %%a
goto :eof 

:chkservice 
sc query %a%
```

Instead of getting the output for the three specified services, I am getting the output equivalent to three times the command `sc query` (I guess).

For debugging I tried checking if the variable `a` getting the values properly or not and tried this version of code:-

```
@echo off
for /f %%a IN ('type services.txt') do call :chkservice %%a
goto :eof

:chkservice
@echo on
echo %a%
```

This code display `spooler` and `dhcp` only. Why not plugplay? I Believe both the issues are related, but not sure how.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function your parameters are in %1,%2,...%n not in `%a%`.
The parameters of a for-loop are nearly invisble outside of that loop.

So your code should looks like

```
@echo off
for /f %%a IN ('type services.txt') do call :chkservice %%a
goto :eof

:chkservice
echo %1
goto :eof
```

Comment: I can easily make out from your answer that how moronic my quesion was. But that's how learn.

Anyways thank a lot for the help.

Comment: In batch, there is nothing easy or obvious